# How to pass several parameters to a function which is iterated by executor.map() from concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

The issue was posted several times here in stackoverflow, but none of them could help me as my case is very specific.

I have a function Myfunction(p1,p2,p3,p4) which need 4 parameters to run.

I need to run Myfunction on multiprocessing way.

I use **concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor** to do this job.

I know how to pass a list as an argument in the executor.map(Myfunction, argument)

But this time, I have a list of tuples which is the list of my 4 arguments for my multiprocessing.

Here is my code:

```
def Myfunction(p_udid,p_systemPort,p_deviceName, p_version, p_os):
    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['platformName'] = p_os
    desired_caps['platformVersion'] = p_version
    desired_caps['deviceName'] = p_deviceName
    desired_caps['udid'] = p_udid
    desired_caps['noReset'] = 'true'



if __name__ == '__main__':
    list=[('41492968379078','4730','S6S5IN3G','6','Android'),('53519716736397','4731','S6S5IN3G','6','Android'),('0123456789ABCDEF','4732','20','7','Android')]
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        multiprocesses = executor.map(Myfunction, list)
```

Of course I get an error :

> concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback:  """ Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py",
>   line 239, in _process_worker
>       r = call_item.fn(*call_item.args, **call_item.kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py",
>   line 198, in _process_chunk
>       return [fn(*args) for args in chunk]   File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py",
>   line 198, in 
>       return [fn(*args) for args in chunk] TypeError: Myfunction() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'p_systemPort',
>   'p_deviceName', 'p_version', and 'p_os' """
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "E:/DropboxBACKUP14112018/Cff/Python/project_GITHUB/test2.py", line
>   24, in 
>       for multiprocess in multiprocesses:   File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py",
>   line 483, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
>       for element in iterable:   File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures_base.py",
>   line 598, in result_iterator
>       yield fs.pop().result()   File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures_base.py",
>   line 435, in result
>       return self.__get_result()   File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures_base.py",
>   line 384, in __get_result
>       raise self._exception TypeError: Myfunction() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'p_systemPort', 'p_deviceName', 'p_version', and
>   'p_os

I tried different stuff from all the answers similar to my issue, but I didn't succeed.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: @Cff: There are 5 arguments, go with `Myfunction(*args)`.

Comment: Thanks @stovfl it doesn't show anymore error message, but my function is not running. As you guessed, I tried to run some smartphone automation with appium & python.
So I tested by hand the function :
Myfunction('53519716736397','4731','S6S5IN3G','6','Android')
Myfunction('41492968379078','4730','S6S5IN3G','6','Android')

And it works.

But when I tried to run it with multiprocessing:
multiprocesses = executor.map(Myfunction, *list)

I didn't get error message, but I didn't see the function runing the test on smartphones. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: ***idea why?***: Don't use `*list`, note the `*`, add a `print(args)` at top of `Myfunction(*args)`

Comment: Ok. it prints the args... it is passing the each tuple as 1 arg. Look what it shows the print(args): (('41492968379078', '4730', 'S6S5IN3G', '6', 'Android'),)
(('53519716736397', '4731', 'S6S5IN3G', '6', 'Android'),)
(('0123456789ABCDEF', '4732', '20', '7', 'Android'),). So that means it is passing the list of tuples as arguments, instead of passing the items of 1 tuple.

Comment: I have a list of tuple, executor.map need to pass 1 tuple of 5 items as 5arguments. But for the moment it is passing 1 list of 4 tuples (which contains 5 items). SO as a result, Myfunction receive 3 tuples of 5 items as arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you can make it work:

```
def Myfunction(*args):

    p_udid,p_systemPort,p_deviceName, p_version, p_os = args[0]

    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['platformName'] = p_os
    desired_caps['platformVersion'] = p_version
    desired_caps['deviceName'] = p_deviceName
    desired_caps['udid'] = p_udid
    desired_caps['noReset'] = 'true'
    return desired_caps

def cpu_tasks(func, *args):

    # set chunksize to be even 
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as tp:
        result = tp.map(func, chunksize=10, *args)
    return list(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lst=[('41492968379078','4730','S6S5IN3G','6','Android'),('53519716736397','4731','S6S5IN3G','6','Android'),('0123456789ABCDEF','4732','20','7','Android')]
    ans = cpu_tasks(Myfunction, *[lst])

    print(ans)

[{'platformName': 'Android',
  'platformVersion': '6',
  'deviceName': 'S6S5IN3G',
  'udid': '41492968379078',
  'noReset': 'true'},
 {'platformName': 'Android',
  'platformVersion': '6',
  'deviceName': 'S6S5IN3G',
  'udid': '53519716736397',
  'noReset': 'true'},
 {'platformName': 'Android',
  'platformVersion': '7',
  'deviceName': '20',
  'udid': '0123456789ABCDEF',
  'noReset': 'true'}]
```

Comment: Usage of `*[lst]` is not required as `list` **is a seqence**.

Comment: `*[lst]` ensures that functions gets a unpacked sequences of a tuple.

Comment: It breaks the multiprocessing. i mean test are running one by one on each smartphone in a sequence.  But you help me so much to format  my args!!! Thank you so much. I use pieces of your code to transform mine and it woks!!! Have a great weekend!

Comment: You can use `ProcessPool` from the `pathos` module to get it to work without breaking the multiprocessing. It's the same syntax -- just replace `ProcessPoolExecutor` with `pathos.pools.ProcessPool`.